# How Can I know the type of Printer installed (Laser, DotMatrix, Label etc) on network and access it

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I have a requirement of fetching all the network printers and displaying them in 3 dropdown based on the type of printer like Laser, Dot-Matrix , Label Printer. I have fetched all the network as :

var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");

```
var result =  (from ManagementBaseObject nprinter in printerQuery.Get()
               select new PrinterConfig
               {
                    PrinterName = nprinter.GetPropertyValue("Name") as String, 
                    Status = (String) nprinter.GetPropertyValue("Status"), 
                    IsDefaultPrinter = (bool) nprinter.GetPropertyValue("Default"),
                    IsNetworkPrinter = (bool) nprinter.GetPropertyValue("Network"),
                    IsLocalPrinter = (bool)nprinter.GetPropertyValue("Local")
               }).ToList();
```

But how can I know the type of the printer so that I can bind them to corresponding dropdowns. I have searched a lot but could not find a way to do it.